# Refactor dependency between services with Java and Spring

Tags: java, spring, service, dependency-injection

I run into a bad practice - creating a dependency between two services and I am not sure what is the best strategy to refactor this and improve it.

Here is my example, I have a `PurchaseServiceImpl` that implements my `PurchaseService` interface and in this `PurchaseServiceImpl` I inject my `CustomerService` and `ProductService`:

```
@Service
public class PurchaseServiceImpl implements PurchaseService { 
    // TODO Refactor this dependency between services
    @Inject
    private CustomerService customerService;
    // TODO Refactor this dependency between services
    @Inject
    private ProductService productService;
```

And here I use `customerService` to fetch a Customer and `productService` to fetch Product from backend respectively:

```
private Customer getCustomer(long id) throws BackendException {
   try {
      return customerService.getCustomer(id);
   } catch (CustomerNotFoundException e) {
      throw new BackendException(e);
   }
}

private ProductDetails getProductDetails(long id) throws BackendException {
   try {
      return productService.getProductDetails(id);
   } catch (ProductNotFoundException e) {
      throw new BackendException(e);
   }
}
```

What would be your best strategy to attack this kind of practice? Currently it is easy like that, but feels like debt that needs to be rather paid attention to.

Comment: What practice are you having problems with?

Comment: I don't want to create dependencies between services (like I have done above).

Comment: Why exactly do you think this is a bad practice?

Comment: I don't want my UI service to communicate directly with my backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem with one service (the purchase service) using two other services. It would be problematic if two services had a circular dependency, i.e. used each other.

Comment: Well, I am thinking about introducing a Facade, so that my UI communicates through the Facade with the services, instead directly. There are no circular dependencies so far, and I don't think I will run into this problem. I am only collecting opinions from more experienced developers or ones that had similar experiences and I want to know how did they approach them.

Comment: Having a Facade is a good design idea :-) But I've seen many applications where services use other services. This works fine as long as there are no circular dependencies, as mentioned above.